# IOS/Objective-C: Passing data (array) and receiving detailed strings

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass data (array) with PrepareForSegue into a detailed VC. The destination VC has a label that receives a string. I thought I could transform the array into a string, and the rest was straightforward. This was achieved, though, but kind of wrongly, because, obviously, the text I get, regardless the row I click, returns me the whole object...And my goal is to get details of a specific row...Can someone help me? Guess this is basic stuff, but this is my first app...The method PrepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {

        NSString *places = [_spots componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

        DetailViewController * destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.detailedText =  places;
}
```

EDIT:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSManagedObject *ls = [self.spots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Table Spots are: %@", ls);
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [ls valueForKey:@"name"]]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"city.jpg"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `NSString *places = [_spots objectAtIndex:[myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]`?

Comment: With your suggestion the app crashes when hiting the row...

Comment: If you show `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, we may have an idea of your dataSource, and what it looks like, what you want to do exactly, and if it crashes, showing the crash log could be usefull...

Comment: the log: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x798ec800

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to `performSegue()` on a row selection and you want to pass a data specific to the selected row. In order to do this you can use the `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRows()` method, which is going to return an array with the `indexPaths` of all selected rows. Then you can get the `UITableViewCells` for this `indexPaths` and get their data.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string value to the perforSegue method as the sender:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detail" sender:[_spots objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {
        DetailViewController * destination = segue.destinationViewController;
        destination.detailedText = sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: It also crashes with this log: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x798ec800'